# simple chart using divs

Tags: javascript, css

i am using the following to produce a chart

```js
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++){
  let rect = document.createElement('div')
  rect.style.backgroundColor = '#dd21d1'
  rect.style.height = Math.random() +'px'
  rect.style.width='.5px'
  rect.style.transform = `scaleY(100) translateX(${i}px)`
  document.body.appendChild(rect)
}
```

however even though my y coordinates are always zero, at least that's what i think , instead of seeing the rectangles in one line it seems that they are added vertically, any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Div's have `display: block`, which will cause them to push other content to the next line. You can fix this by telling those divs to be `inline-block`, by adding this line before you append to the body:

`rect.style.display = 'inline-block'`

The entire snippet would be updated to look like so:

```
for(let i=0;i<1000;i++){
  let rect = document.createElement('div')
  rect.style.backgroundColor = '#dd21d1'
  rect.style.height = Math.random() +'px'
  rect.style.width='.5px'
  rect.style.transform = `scaleY(100) translateX(${i}px)`
  rect.style.display = 'inline-block'
  document.body.appendChild(rect)
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot that resolved it, thought that transforms do not require that

Answer (score 1):

The CSS default `display` property is `block`.  You likely want to use `inline-block` to create a chart.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)